# Bulk binding class methods in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was looking for a way to bind react class methods to `this` in the constructor all at once, because I got tired of typing `this._anotherFunction = this._anotherFunction.bind(this)` 10 times for each component.

I haven't seen anyone else posting solutions for this and thought it would be useful to share my answer.

Interested to see if anyone else has similar implementations, or if there are any issues with the way I implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting this issue - the previous suggestion to use arrow functions as class properties have some drawbacks, including performance implications. (Albeit an arguably negligible performance implication, but one worth noting).

**New Proposed Solution:**

- create a new class that `extends` `Component`, e.g. `ComponentAutoBind`
- any sub-component that `extends` `ComponentAutoBind` will automatically have its own methods bound to the class instance
- exclude React lifecycle methods from binding

[See this gist for proposed solution](https://gist.github.com/townofdon/5d05175ab103dfd0e0e6347fd65e71e6)

[Working codepen example](https://codepen.io/don-townsend/pen/XGKMaz)

I realize that extending `Component` may not be best practice but my implementation is only affecting the constructor - all other `Component` class properties are untouched.

---

Here are some links for the unconvinced:

- https://medium.com/@forsakenharmony/you-should-maybe-mention-that-the-arrow-function-in-the-class-body-is-just-syntactic-sugar-c7bfb3383bef
- https://blog.usejournal.com/arrow-functions-are-disrupting-react-components-63662d35f97b
- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36 - only discusses Render method but same principle applies to class properties

Comment: Other possibility: simply use [babel transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) per this article: https://medium.com/quick-code/react-quick-tip-use-class-properties-and-arrow-functions-to-avoid-binding-this-to-methods-29628aca2e25

Answer (score 0):

Given the following React class functions:

```
_showModal() {}
_hideModal() {}
// etc.
```

In the constructor I added:

```
// bind all of the class's methods to the class
bindClassMethods.bind(this)([
  '_showModal',
  '_hideModal',
  // etc.
]);
```

Here's the re-usable util function I wrote to pull this off:

```
export function bindClassMethods(classMethods = []) {
  if (!_.isArray(classMethods)) {
    console.error(`Need to pass an array to bindClassMethods().`);
    return;
  }
  classMethods.map(fnc => {
    if (!this[fnc]) {
      console.error(
        `Warning: func ${fnc} is not defined! It probably has been removed from this class' methods.`
      );
    } else {
      this[fnc] = this[fnc].bind(this);
    }
  });
}
```

I found the console logs useful for reminding myself when I forgot to remove or update a function binding.

Comment: why don't you just use arrow functions? e.g. `showModal = () => {}`

Comment: There are performance issues related to using arrow functions as each re-rendering of the component will lead to a new anonymous function being created.

Comment: Or were you referring to using arrow functions outside of the render method?

Comment: outside render.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but changing `_showModal() {}` to `_showModal = () => {}` would remove the need for binding in the first place?

Comment: indeed it would

Comment: awesome. Just tested and it looks like this works just as well. Thanks @dashton!